# Create public profiles for users in django

Tags: python, django, view

I created a profile view for users and I want everyone to be able to see it without having to log in
But when I click on the profile while not having logged in, it automatically logs into the account of the user I clicked on!
How can I fix it?

This is the view

```
def public_profile(request, username):
    user = 
User.objects.get(username=username)
    return render(request, 'users/public_profile.html', {"user": user})
```

This is the url

```
path('<str:username>/profile/', public_profile, name='public-profile'),
```

Comment: I don't think it logs in, it simply renders that page. Likely because you pass it as `user` to the template, which is normally the name used for the logged in user. Pass it with another name, for example `{'profile': user }`.

Answer (score 1):

It likely does not log in. But some context processors will add certain elements to the context. For example the [**`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth.auth`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) context processor will add a value for the `'user'` key to the context if the user is logged in. A template that thus works with `{{ user }}`, might assume this is the logged in user.

You therefore better pass the user you want to show under a different name, for example `profile`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def public_profile(request, username):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    return render(request, 'users/public_profile.html', {'profile' : user})
```

Answer (score 0):

As Willem Van Onsem says, the `user` variable is used by the [Authentication middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) to represent the current logged user, so your `user` object is replaced with that. Try changing the name of the variable you use.